# Get widget width using YUI JS

Tags: yui

var _TooltipHandler = {

```
toolTipOverlay : null,

onMouseOver : function (e)
{   
    _TooltipHandler.toolTipOverlay.set("bodyContent", this.get('alt'));
    var region= this.get('region');
    var elmLeft = region.left;
    var windowWidth = this.get('winWidth');        
    _TooltipHandler.toolTipOverlay.set("align", {node:this, 
             points:[_yui.WidgetPositionExt.BL, _yui.WidgetPositionExt.TR]});           
    _TooltipHandler.toolTipOverlay.show();
    e.preventDefault();
},
```

}
Hello guys,

Give me a way to find the width of the current toolTipOverlay div. We do not use jquery so please be specific related to yui 3.0 js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: widget has a 'width' attribute. Does that not work? http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/classes/Widget.html#attr_width

Answer (score 0):

The width of the widget (tooltip inherited from Widget) is the width of the `boundingBox` node;

> ```
> var bb_width = widget_instance.get('boundingBox').getStyle('width');
> ```

Check the Widget's Basic Attributes : http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/widget/#attributes